# Efficient way to get bit in binary expansion of [0,1] real in Mathematica?

Tags: binary, wolfram-mathematica, expansion

As is well known, any real in [0,1] can be written as a binary expansion in base 1/2:

```
x = b1 * 1/2^1 + b2 * 1/2^2 + ...
```

I would like an efficient way to get **bi** for a given **x** and index **i**, and I don't think there's any built-in way to do that in Mathematica. IntegerDigits and RealDigits don't seem to be able to help, and none of the related functions are pertinent.

The obvious solution is to do the manual conversion, but I was hoping to avoid that. Am I missing something?

**EDIT**: for future reference, what I was looking for can be done this way,

```
BinaryExpansionBit[p, j] := RealDigits[p, 2, 1, -j][[1]][[1]]
```

where

```
BinaryExpansionBit[x, i]
```

gives the **bi** I was talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "efficient".  Mathematica can easily convert to binary, as this [Wolfram Alpha example](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.12345%20in%20binary) shows.

Otherwise what you are looking for is the parity of the integer part of `x * 2^i`.

Comment: Thank you. My question was a bit silly, and thanks for bearing with me nonetheless. :)

Answer (score 4):

I don't see what's wrong with RealDigits.

`rd=RealDigits[0.1,2]`

gives a nice binary expansion:

```
(* out: 
    {{1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,
   0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
  1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0}, -3} 
*)
```

testing:

```
rd[[1]].Table[1/2^(n - rd[[2]]), {n, Length[rd[[1]]]}]

(* out: 3602879701896397 / 36028797018963968, which is 0.1*)
```

The second element of `RealDigit`'s output tells you location of the first element with respect to the decimal point. So, for a real r, `0<r<1` your `bi = rd[[1,i-rd[[2]]]`.